# Short-circuit list, type of `(a -> Either e a) -> [a] -> Either e [a]` ... monadic operation?

Tags: haskell, monads, either

Consider the following function:

```hs
validateList :: (a -> Either e a) -> [a] -> Either e [a]
validateList validate []     = Right []
validateList validate (x:xs) =
    case validate x of
      Left err -> Left err
      Right y  -> case validateList validate xs of
                    Left err -> Left err
                    Right ys -> Right $ y:ys
```

Is there a way to write this in a more concise way? Maybe using the `>>=` operator?

A bit to think about because there are actually two monads here: `[]` and `Either`, although `List` here is not acting as a monad but just more so as a `Traversable`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe your `Traversable` idea is exactly what you need.

```
validateList :: (a -> Either e a) -> [a] -> Either e [a]
validateList = traverse
```

This is `traverse` using the `Either a` applicative functor and the `[]` traversable/foldable.

Note that this does indeed lazy/short-circuiting: as soon as a `Left` is found the rest of the input list is no longer demanded. Here is a test using an infinite list:

```
> validateList (\n -> case n of 1 -> Right 56 ; 2 -> Left "fdsf") [1..]
Left "fdsf"
```